# Why does my Leaflet circle only show as a dot?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to add circles to my map, but for some reason the circles only show as dots, irrespective of the radius size.

```js
var circle = L.circle(map.unproject([9541, 7658], map.getMaxZoom()), {
    radius: 500
}).addTo(map);
```

I'm using pixel coordinates, but as you can see I'm converting them, so even though I only get dots on the map, they show at the right coordinates. I would hope this isn't the issue, but...?

I've successfully added circleMarkers, but the radius doesn't grow when zooming. At least not that I could see.

So the question is: how can I get the dots to show as circles?

Using Leaflet 1.9.3

#### Update

It appears that with pixel coordinates you need to enter a really high value for the radius. Thought I had already tried this before asking the question but apparently not.

```js
var circle = L.circle(map.unproject([9541, 7658], map.getMaxZoom()), {
    radius: 50000
}).addTo(map);
```

Unfortunately they're all showing at different sizes, even with the same radius, but that's a different question...

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/jpJOcbR8zS2evbbR).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally misread your question and gave an incorrect answer, sorry. Circle radius is static. I think that the best way to change it with zoom level would be to use a zoom event listener:

```js
let currZoom = map.getZoom();
let circles = [/* Store your circles here as you create them */];

map.on("zoomend", () => {
  const zoomDiff = map.getZoom() - currZoom;
  
  currZoom = map.getZoom();
  for (const circle of circles) {
    circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() * 2 ** zoomDiff);
  }
});
```

It's been a while since I've worked with Leaflet, but I think that will do the trick.

Edited to account for your comment regarding multiple circles.

Comment: Thank you. This won't work because I have many dynamically generated markers created in a loop. Plus, the problem still remains: my circle is a dot when the map loads.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for you having multiple circles. Regarding the size, instead of a 500 initial radius, try `500 * 2 ** (map.getMaxZoom() - map.getZoom())`.

Comment: Still no luck. The circles appear as dots on load, and when zoomed they get a little bigger but then disappear back into dots and at the wrong coordinates.

Comment: Looks like you just need to enter a really high value for the radius ‍♂️

Comment: I couldn't get `circle` to work properly, so I changed to using `circleMarker` and implemented your solution and it's working perfectly. Thank you!